What is the reason for the difference between the expected input tensor order for LSTM and Conv1d?
What is the reason for the difference between the expected input tensor order for LSTM and Conv1d?
Say I have an input tensor for time series data of shape (Batch Size, Sequence Length, Features). If I wanted to pass this into an LSTM layer I just add batch_first=true and I'm good to go. However, if I wanted to perform a temporal convolution I would need to run permute(0, 2, 1) before the conv1d layer. Likewise, I would need to perform permute for the LSTM if I had the data input the other way around.
It would seem to be that these layers, despite working on the same kind of data, expect different input shapes.
